# Out of Range exception while accessing the files in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Below is the code I used to access the asset file for a metro app I am working on.

```
        async void readFileFromDisk (string fileName, string fileType)
    {
        string fileContent;

        StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(readStream))
            {
                UInt32 numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((UInt32)readStream.Size);
                fileContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
            }
        }
```

This code is run in the handler for Loaded event for the page. **I am currently getting an exception saying "Value does not fall in range".** The error occurs at the first line itself, where I try to get storagefile handle from the installation folder.

On debugging, the fileName string comes out to be Null. I guess, I should be moving the code to some event which is fired at a later stage in page lifecycle, but can't seem to figure out what is the best place to do it. Suggestions??

P.S. I need to read this file before any interaction from user, as it reads the data for the level, that user will be interacting with.

Edit:

Missed a couple things. 
The below function is called from the handler for loaded event.

```
void Game_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //read all level files to the strings
        readFileFromDisk("//Assets/Levels/Start" + selectedLevel + ".txt", "Start");
```

This handler basically calls above function for different file paths, in similar manner. The string selected level is static variable, while the fileName string is created from the same.

Edit 2:

Found the issue, but solution is still far away. The return type of readFileFromDist method is causing trouble. Changed it to Task, and this part works fine, but I get "Object reference not set to an instance" error. Tried to convert Game_Loaded event handler to async too, to use await operators, but that gives me compiler error for "wrong return type".

SO, I tried removing async completely, but I guess I can't do that. There is no way to open files without using async function. So, I essentially need a way to call the readFileFromDisk function, using await, and continue with rest of the code execution once the task is completed. Something like, "IsCompleted" event for the awaited calls for the function.

Comment: You should also show the code where you are calling the method; you say that `fileName` is a static variable, but it's clearly a method parameter in the code you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, My Bad. I guess, multitasking is not my forte, if I make silly mistakes like this. Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not part of your problem, but in `Game_Loaded` you're calling an `async` method without an `await`.  This could cause issues once you've fixed your current bug!  Your `async` method should also have a return value - see [this post](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/why-you-should-almost-never-write-void-asynchronous-methods/) for more info.

Comment: Actually, the async method does not return any values. It simply reads file and stores it in a class variable. Do I still need to create a Task<bool> or similar return type and throw away that value? Also, I don't think I can get rid of async function and convert it to normal function. Can I do that, considering the files to be read are only few KB in size? I can run the file read function in UI thread itself, if it is allowed.

Comment: One more question. Do I need to copy these files to bin folder manually? I have just added references in Assets folder.

Comment: an `async` method should have a return type of (non-generic) `Task` if it has no return data.  You don't need to supply or collect that value in your code.

Comment: I tried doing Task<>, but it gave me error. So, as per suggestions from VS, I changed it to void. Anyways let me try it out and update on the matter.

Tried it. I was doing a silly mistake of adding <> at the end. Just changed return type to Task, and it works. But, now, the calls are not awaited, so I get "Object not set to an instance" error, later on, while using these strings for manipulation. 

Also, StackOverflow suggesting to move it to chat. So, I will be updating this same comment for next edits.

Comment: *NOT* `Task<>` (the generic), but `Task` (non-generic).  Did you read the page that I linked?

Comment: Yes, I did read it. I updated the comment. I was doing a silly mistake. Rectified it, and it works, but new issue pops up now. I can't use await in Loaded event handler. See the update to the question. It gives me error if I change Loaded event handler to async. I want the system to wait for the call to finish and then continue with rest of code in Loaded handler. Changing it to async is not possible. I can remove these function calls in a separate async function, but again, I can't use await in Loaded handler without using async. It is kind of a circular loop, that I am stuck in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Needed to use "ms:appx///Assets/filename.txt" instead of "//Assets/filename.txt".